# How can i rename column title dynamically, in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Recent days, i am researching multi-language reports in Power BI. and i find a video from Youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJryD2dXVVw). however it stucked(at 13:00), because Power BI seems hard-coded column title in its visuals.

[image]

But, after drag column into a table/matrix(or other visuals), actually, I can rename (to whatever i want). So, I get a idea. Is it possible to rename this title dynamically? inside Power BI, or with C# code, PowerShell scripts outside Power BI?

Comment: What do you mean by "**dynamically**"? How do you want it to be changed?

Comment: I have some reports need translate into few languages. When doing translation, i need open the report and change the title or column title, and then save another copy of pbix file, one copy for each language. The problem is the reports need update regularly, and i have to do the title or column title translation work again, and again.  So, I want to know, is it possible to change visual title, column title by program dynamically. It reduces lot of manually work, risk of mistakes.

Comment: Where you able to acheive @L.W